# import cv2 >> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Tags: python, opencv

```
    import cv2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
although it already installed but run in cmd only 
not working in any IDE like Vs or spyder or Jupyter
```

i wanna to make IDE import OpenCv

Comment: `pip install opencv-python` in the command prompt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
try:
   import opencv-python
except:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'opencv-python'])
```

Alternatively, open a console in your IDE and execute the following:

`pip install opencv-python`

Your IDE probably uses a different python instance to the one your console uses

Comment: `pip install cv2` **will fail** because the package isn't named that. I also wouldn't recommend just starting a subprocess if an import doesn't exist. that's a side effect you should announce to whoever runs the script.

Comment: edited to update package name and pasting a subprocess command may be more convenient if the user can't work out how to open console in his IDE. Given that he needed to ask the question, I think it's a fair assumption to make

Comment: now you just made it wrong in a different way. please limit yourself to answering questions on subjects you have experience in. from your answer and your edits, it is clear that you don't have any experience with OpenCV in python. OpenCV questions aren't as trivial as most general python questions. when prowling the python tag, watch out for and avoid questions that are clearly about a specific library/technology, not just python.